# Guest account works, but regular account does not

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, login, lightdm

My System is Samsung R580 and I am having a problem logging in to Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS.

Yesterday, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, and have not been able to log into my `admin` account since. Once I put in my password and press enter, the computer displays the Ubuntu wallpaper, and nothing else. No icons, nothing. But the guest account works fine. I've tried reinstalling `GDM` and `Lightdm`, `Nvidia-Prime` and `Nvidia-current`.

Also tried resetting **Unity** **with Unity Tweak Tool**, but still does not work. I have been using Ubuntu for a few months, so I am not yet that familiar with the way this OS works. If someone can please help me fix this, that'd be awesome, since all my stuff for school is on this computer.

Comment: See comment below

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Take your time reading this first sentence:

Before typing the following keystroke, remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> *is your friend*.  This is the keystroke to type to get back to where you are right now.  (probably your guest session) OK? Remember? Sure?

OK! Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to TTY1, which is a full screen terminal (and only a terminal: no mouse, no dash, no nothing).  Try to log in there.

It *does* show your user name when you type it after the `login:` prompt, but does not show anything when you type your password!  Oh, and you have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you typed your user name and before it shows you the password prompt.

Now type the following commands: (assuming `user` is your old user name)

```
sudo adduser user2
```

and follow the instructions on-screen.  If you're *not on a US keyboard*, don't use any "special" characters like £ à ŷ ü nor any numbers unless they're from your keypad.

Now type the following commands:

```
sudo adduser user2 adm 
sudo adduser user2 cdrom
sudo adduser user2 sudo
sudo adduser user2 dip
sudo adduser user2 plugdev
sudo adduser user2 lpadmin
sudo adduser user2 sambashare
```

(If any of the above gives an error like `group not found`, don't worry: I'm trying to be thorough)

Now, log out of the guest session and log in as "user2" and come back here to this site

Ah you're back!  ;-)  Please test now if you still have your problem...  No?  OK!

Now,

1. Open the file manager
2. Browse to the `/home/user` directory
3. **Copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
4. Check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

## Done!

Comment: **C by user copied from Q to C:** I followed all the steps you gave me, but the problem persists. Even when I use live CDs, I am unable to access my original user account/folder. I'm trying to figure out a way to copy my important stuff to my external hard drive in case if I have to reinstall the OS. I started Ubuntu via disc, clicked on "Try Ubuntu," in an attempt to copy my files to an external hard drive, but it wouldn't let me; I kept getting errors stating that the folder "doesn't contain a recognizable (or mountable) file system," and "you do not have permission to access this folder."

Comment: After you created the new account, did you see the `/home/olduser/Documents` folder?  Also, if you leave an additional answer or edit your question I don't see any message popping up in my inbox so only accidentally saw your message...  Just press "add a comment" below to give me a notification.  Also [take the tour](http://www.askubuntu.com/tour) to know how this site works: it's not a forum!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That's my case, hope that can help you.

I find the file owner of ~/.Xauthority have been changed to root. ( that file should belong to account user )

1. `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to go to TTY1.
2. check the home directory of normal account. e.g. user1
3. change file owner from root to user1. e.g. `sudo chown user1:user1 .Xauthority`
4. back to GUI screen by `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, and log in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact situation happened today. Only the wall paper showed up after logging into my account. No launchers or desktop icons. The guest account worked fine. Re-installing unity, compiz, nvidia drivers and the linux kernel did not help at all.

It turns out that the problem was because I changed a few lines in ~/.profile and left a syntax error, as suggested by this post: 
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/188337

The solution is to make a backup of ~/.profile and delete ~/.profile.

Then the desktop showed up after reboot. Now I just need to restore ~/.profile and fix the error.

Hope this help other people who run into the same problem.