# /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf gets erased each time I restart, and I can't use internet without it (16.04)

Tags: networking, resolv.conf

I have been solving issues with my ubuntu - windows partition. 
So after having an issue with the clock of the system and i think this triggering that I couldn't log into my user (it just bounced back) but being free to log like guest, so I created a new user like suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591160/guest-account-works-but-regular-account-does-not).

So, it worked, but now I couldn't load anything although the icon appeared like connected, both wireless and ethernet. So I found a solution... somewhere, that said to add to `/etc/resolv.conf`

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

`nameserver 8.8.4.4`

So, I found it but it had a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and it didn't exists, so I made one with only said lines. And the internet worked then!!

But when I restart the computer, `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is gone so I have to make one again each time.

How can I fix this? Apparently there aren't any other symlinks broken, and I have also done [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800526/ubuntu-16-04-erases-etc-resolv-conf-after-restart) with no result. Thanks everybody

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and answering 'Yes' when it asks you if you want to prepare /etc/resolv.conf for dynamic updates.

Comment: @Antonio Kuri Have you tried some of these solutions?

Comment: Yeah, I just did. Something is missing

Comment: @AntonioKuri I've updated my answer. Try from the beginning again. Changed step 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should restore the *resolv.conf* symbolic link and add required nameservers to */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base*. Follow these steps:

1. Reinstall *resolvconf* package:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall resolvconf
   ```
2. Add required nameservers to */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base*:

   ```
   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base'
   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base'
   ```
3. Regenerate *resolv.conf*:

   ```
   $ sudo resolvconf -u
   ```
4. Restart your network interfaces:

   ```
   $ sudo ifdown -a ; sudo ifup -a
   ```

Comment: When running step 3, it gives back: run-parts: failed to open directory /etc/resolvconf/update.d: No such file or directory

Comment: @AntonioKuri Ok. Updated my answer. Try again from the beginning. Changed step 1.

Comment: NetworkManager just crashed while doing nothing. Executable path: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager

Comment: Did you tried restarting NetworkManager?

Comment: Doing the stated worked. Now I restart and the connection works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the resolv.conf is not updated automatically. You can reconfigure it

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need resolvconf, if you don't have it installed,

`sudo apt-get install resolvconf`

then change the configuration using this file.

`sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

This make the changes permanent.

Comment: It does make that persistent but doesn't help to fix the connection. No site loads